# Injecting Resources Into UIComponent (aka does CDI work here?)

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, composite-component

I am writing a (composite) component that needs to interact with my DAO.   Here is how the Java part is declared:

```
@FacesComponent(value="selectLocation")
public class SelectLocation extends UINamingContainer {
```

To get the DAO object, I tried the CDI annotation:

```
    @Inject private LocationControl lc;
```

And that didn't work so I tried the Faces annotation:

```
    @ManagedProperty (value = "@{locationControl}") private LocationControl lc;
```

Both cases nothing happens -- the property lc ends up as null after the constructor finishes.

I use CDI in all my backing beans and it all works.  This would be using Weld inside GlassFish 3.1.1.  Any suggestions on how to get the resource?

Comment: Dang I thought you were onto something there -- I tried java.inject.Named but still no joy.

Comment: Adding a @RequestScoped causes the application to be unable to deploy: WELD-001437 Normal scoped bean class javax.faces.component.UIComponent is not proxyable because the type is final or it contains a final method public final javax.faces.component.TransientStateHelper javax.faces.component.UIComponent.getTransientStateHelper().

Comment: The created component allows the user to select a Location object by browsing through a data base (JPA) of such objects.  For that I need access to the DAO either directly or indirectly.   But my DAOs are no different from my other CDI-managed beans -- they just have JPA annotations inside them like @PersistenceContext in them.  I am reading the CDI specification now to see if there is something in beans.xml that can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a work-around for now, which is to basically put in the boiler-plate code that CDI et. al. is supposed to do away with.   I now have this method:

```
public LocationControl getLocationControl() {
    if (lc != null) return lc;
    FacesContext fc = getFacesContext();
    Object obj = fc.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(fc, "#{locationControl}", LocationControl.class);
    if (obj instanceof LocationControl) lc = (LocationControl) obj;
    return lc;
}
```

I would like to know if anyone has a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it also works for components, but with CDI + MyFaces CODI you have @Advanced to mark e.g. Phase-Listeners which should be able to use @Inject. If it doesn't work, you could create a feature request in their JIRA. They are pretty fast and there are frequent releases.

Or you use:
MyBean myBean = BeanManagerProvider.getInstance().getContextualReference(MyBean.class);
manually.

Answer (score 2):

> *There is a way to do this work without workarounds?*

Yes, just use a backing bean the usual way.

```
<x:someComponent value="#{someBean.someProperty}" />
```

Wrap if necessary in a reusable tagfile/composite to keep it DRY:

```
<my:someComponent />
```